# Streaming json data stored in database

Tags: java, json, database, streaming

Large json object is stored in database in a column. Need to use Gson streaming to fetch the json data in streaming manner.

json object with array and objects is stored database column.Now i have to fetch database objects based on the requirement or if its an array need to load one by one array elements and parse it for the paths given.

Comment: Which DB  is being used

Comment: I am now using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Current MySQL version supports JSON format.You can play with that.
Thanks